# How to tell if a datetime string has a date component in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I Need your help again, here is what I ultimately want to do:

- Create a DateTime object with a date (only) following a given format (so far it's okay)
- Alter it with a datetime string following a specified format as well, which can be either a single time of a date and time string.

An example:

We have a single date in a filename that is the base date of the DateTime object. Inside the file are date and time strings, which most of the time are only time. But if the string also holds a date, we have to update the base date accordingly.

A bit difficult to explain, I hope you will understand. I feel the solution is quite obvious but still, I can't find it...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `strtotime('yourTimeString')` https://www.php.net/strtotime

It will parse the string if able and return `false` if not.

Comment: I'll post an example code in the next comment, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As andrew said, strtotime is the solution:

Here is an example:

```
$baseDate = "2013-12-01"; //date in file name
$fullDate = strtotime($timeString, $baseDate); //$timestring is the time or datetime string in the file
```

this will work if $timeString is time only or datetime string, very easy in the end!

Thanks again andrew

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_parse` on the string and then check the hour key.

```
$dateTimeString = "December 7, 1941"; //your string here

$dateArray = date_parse($dateTimeString);

    if ($dateArray["hour"] == "") {

        echo "The string does not contain a time.";

    } else {

        echo "The string contains a time.";

    }
```